# Dynamically coded if statement executed inside an XMLReader while loop (using PHP)

Tags: php, if-statement, dynamic-programming, xmlreader

The if statement code is dynamically being built (based on user values submitted) into the $if_statement variable below, like this:

```
$keyword = trim($_GET["Keyword"]);
if (!empty($keyword)) {
$if_statement = ($keyword == $xpath->evaluate('string(title)', $node));
}

$shopByStore = $_GET["store"];
if (!empty($shopByStore)) {
$if_statement = ($if_statement && $shopByStore == $xpath->evaluate('string(store)', $node));
}
// plus  8 more GET methods retrieving potential user input for the $if_statement variable.
```

Then a very large XML file will be parsed with XMLReader ..

```
$reader = new XMLReader;
$reader->open('products.xml');
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$xpath = new DOMXpath($dom);

while ($reader->read() && $reader->name !== 'product') {
continue;
}
while ($reader->name === 'product') {
$node = $dom->importNode($reader->expand(), TRUE);
```

.. and then this if statement code will test which values are displayed in an XMLReader while loop. Since there can be anywhere between 1 to 10 conditions tested in the if statement (depending on how many GET methods produce empty variables from user input), it would seem less strenuous on the system to test for empty variables only once (prior to the while loop executing) than it would be to test for empty variables during EVERY loop of the while loop. Testing for 10 conditions when (in some cases) only 1 or 2 conditions need to be tested is a waste.

Is there a way to use the if_statement variable (dynamically created above) in the while loop below? Nothing is being displayed below.

```
if ($if_statement) {
$name = $xpath->evaluate('string(name)', $node);
$store = $xpath->evaluate('string(store)', $node);
echo "Name: " . $name . ". ";
echo "Store: " . $store . ". ";

}}
```

Comment: You have a very special way of coding. Not sure what you want to do finally, but pretty sure you are doing it wrong. This is PHP, one of the dumbest language around, don't over-complicate it ;)

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
$relations = array('keyword'=>'title', 'store'=>'store'); // your others conditions relations in there.

while ($reader->read()) {
    if($reader->name !== 'product'){continue;}

    $node = $dom->importNode($reader->expand(), TRUE);
    foreach($relations as $key => $val){
        if(trim($_GET["$key"]) != $xpath->evaluate("string($val)")){
            continue 2;
        }
    }
   $name = $xpath->evaluate('string(name)', $node);
   $store = $xpath->evaluate('string(store)', $node);
   echo "Name: " . $name . ". ";
   echo "Store: " . $store . ". ";
}
```

Couldn't test the code, but this may work with some tinkering.

Hope it helps.